# copy only new data from one workbook to another

Tags: database, excel, copy, vba

Found this code below that copies only "new" data from workbook1 to workbook2. It does what it suppose to but only limited to two columns A and B. My data span all the way to ZQ on every row. I tried to tweak the code for my purpose but its just beyond me. I appreciate any help.

```
Sub CompareArrays()

Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant, arr3() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, nextRow As Long
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim x As Boolean

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm") 'Name of first workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx") 'Name of second workbook
arr1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2:B" & wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
arr2 = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A2:B" & wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value

For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    x = True
    For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        If arr1(i, 1) = arr2(j, 1) Then
            x = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If x = True Then
        k = k + 1
        ReDim Preserve arr3(2, k)
        arr3(1, k - 1) = arr1(i, 2)
        arr3(0, k - 1) = arr1(i, 1)
    End If
Next i

With wb2.Sheets(1)
    nextRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    .Range(.Cells(nextRow, 1), .Cells(nextRow + k, 2)) = Application.Transpose(arr3)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please state more clearly exactly what you want the code to do (with an example ideally), and add in what you have already tried.

Comment: here's a sample workbooks: [Workbook samples](http://jmluzadas.com/WB.zip)

Comment: the code will copy only new data from one workbook to another the only problem with this code is that it only copy 2 columns, I need it to copy all the way to DQ.

Comment: Try replacing `arr1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2:B" & wb1.Sheet....` with `arr1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2:ZQ" & wb1.Sheet....`. Same for `arr2`. Anyway, I would not add that much amount of data to an array, but look for an alternate method.

Comment: CMArg, that's actually the first thing I tried and it didn't do a thing

Comment: you're right. Code is "storing" desired values in `arr3`, but only two of them (the lines below `ReDim Preserve`). Other than hard code all columns, some loop might work. But can't see clearly how to.

Comment: @JCprog How do you determine which row to copy ? what is the criteria ? in the sample code above with 2 columns, it compares the values of column A and column B per row ? You want to compare the values of column A to B , B to C? C to D? A to C? ....... and so on ? what is the criteria to decide which row to copy ?

Comment: Shai Rado, unique ID's are in column A on both workbooks. Compare ID's on both workbooks and only copy over the ones that don't exist in wb2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
Sub CompareArrays()

Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant, arr3() As Variant
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, nextRow As Long
Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
Dim x As Boolean

Set wb1 = Workbooks("Workbook1.xlsm") 'Name of first workbook
Set wb2 = Workbooks("Workbook2.xlsx") 'Name of second workbook
arr1 = wb1.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & wb1.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
arr2 = wb2.Sheets(1).Range("A2:A" & wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Value
k = 1
For i = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
    x = True
    For j = LBound(arr2) To UBound(arr2)
        If arr1(i, 1) = arr2(j, 1) Then
            x = False
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    If x = True Then
        k = k + 1
        pos = Application.Match(arr1(i, 1), arr1, False) + 1 'get position in array
        nextRow = wb2.Sheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        wb2.Sheets(1).Rows(nextRow).EntireRow.Value = wb1.Sheets(1).Rows(pos).EntireRow.Value
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: CMArg, Thanks for the code! this works, however, it also copy even the blank cells. I noticed it with the length of the horizontal scrollbar. This will be problematic when the routine is run for x number of times. Here's the updated sample [workbooks](http://jmluzadas.com/WB.zip) I've been playing around with and hard coded each position in array, your code is also in a module.

Comment: Glad it helps. Instead of `.EntireRow` you can define a range. Regarding the link to sample workbooks, few people will dare to open unknown excel file. And certainly not me.